# Do I have to include catch blocks in Java when calling a method that throws exceptions?

Tags: java, android, exception, ioexception

i create an android application. and typed some codes just like :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
XmlResourceParser xrp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.OneXml);   <==OneXml is a custom xml file in folder res/xml
...
try {
    ....
    xrp.next();
    .... 
} catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch(XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} 
...
```

i found that i can neither delete `catch(IOException e)` nor `catch(XmlPullParserException e)`, when i try to delete one of them, Eclipse marks an error at `xrp.next()` and tells me that ***Unhandled exception type IOException*** or ***Unhandled exception type XmlPullParserException***, so must i add the two `catch`? why does Eclipse ask me to add two `catch` compulsively? Can't the code be compiled successfully without the two `catch`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Exception Handling ways:**
We can handle a 'problem statement' (Problem Statement is any statement which can throw an exception) in two ways.

- Enclose the statement in `try-catch` block.
- Append a `throws` clause in the method header.

**Handling Exception in Overridden Methods:**
If you are overriding a method in child class. Then you cannot append extra throws clause in its signature. In your case `onCreate` is a method in parent class, which is overridden in child class hence we can not append throws clause in it header. So you have to enclose any 'Problem Statements' within `onCreate` method in try-catch blocks.

**Examples:**
Enclose the statement in `try-catch` block.

```
public void myMethod(){
        try{
            // Problem Statement
        }catch(IllegalAccessException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Append a `throws` clause in the method header.

```
public void myMethod()
        throws IllegalAccessException, NullPointerException{
            // Problem Statement
    }
```

**Examples Overridden Methods:**
**Valid throws clause:** A throws clause in overridden method is valid if    it is also in parent'smethod.

```
public class Parent {
    public int method() 
        throws IllegalAccessException,NullPointerException, Exception {
        return 0;
    }
}
public class child extends Parent {
    // throws is part of method because parent method
    // have throws clause
    @Override
    public int method() 
        throws IllegalAccessException, NullPointerException,
            Exception {
            //Problem Statement
        return super.method();
    }
}
```

**Invalid throws clause:** A throws clause in overridden method is invalid if it is not present in parent's method.

```
public class Parent {
    public int method(){
        return 0;
    }
}

public class child extends Parent {
    //**Error:** We can not append throws clause in the method because
    // parent method do not have a throws clause
    @Override
    public int method() 
        throws IllegalAccessException, NullPointerException,
            Exception {
            //Problem Statement
        return super.method();
    }
}
```

So we have to modify our child class's method and remove `throws` clause as parent method do not contain throws clause in this particular situation. We have to handle exception through `try-catch` block.

```
public class child extends Parent {
    //**Error:** We can not append throws clause in the method because
    // parent method do not have a throws clause
    @Override
    public int method() {
        try{
            // Problem Statement
        }catch(IllegalAccessException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not in the habit of downvoting answers, particularly detailed ones, but this is *way* too much information for what is ultimately a very simple question. More words != better answer. It's nothing personal, I just don't feel all the extra verbiage helps explain.

Comment: (If it didn't push what I consider to be better answers to below the fold I wouldn't have bothered.)

Comment: Actually it's really very long, but some of your codes inspired me and i found what made me confused.in fact, i dont know xrp.next() throws the two exception and i must catch them when i invoke the function. Maybe everyone here is trying to tell me the truth, but it's you inspire me.Thanks. and also thank @DaveNewton, for your enthusiastic :)

Answer (score 1):

In Java you have to either catch exceptions or declare the fact that calling the method might result in an exception, like so:

```
public void onSomethingOtherThanCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  throws IOException, XmlPullParserException
{
   // your code without any try/catch
}
```

(`Error` and `RuntimeException` exceptions which can happen any time do not need to be declared in this way.)

Comment: You cannot arbitrarily add `throws` declarations to overridden functions; this will not work for `onCreate`.

Answer (score 0):

That's what checked exceptions mean: you must either catch them, or declare them thrown.

`onCreate` is being overridden and must adhere to the original method's declaration, so either catching them, or doing that part of the work in another method that catches them, is your only option.

See [JLS 11 Exceptions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/exceptions.html), specifically [JLS 11.2.3 Exception Checking](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/exceptions.html#11.2.3), for details.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Eclipse, it's Java!

In a method, code which throws exceptions must reside inside a `try-catch` block unless the `throws` clause for the unhanded exception is used in the method declaration itself.

Answer (score 0):

If your complaint is that you have to type *two* catch clauses, it is possible to catch them all in a single clause,

```
catch (Exception e) {
      // dostuff here
   }
```

However, unless all you plan to do is print a stack trace or log the exception, this practice is frowned upon.  In the long run it will make the code harder to debug and maintain.

Java 7 allows you to [catch multiple exceptions in a single clause](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html), but Android doesn't yet support Java 7.